# Does q-function remain the inverse of CDF for any type of distribution?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, quantiles

I [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) the the Quantile Function commonly known as q-function is the inverse of the CDF for a normal distribution.

$Q(x) = 1 - Q(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)\,\!,$

where `Φ(x)` is the cumulative distribution function of the normal Gaussian distribution.

Does this apply to any kind of distribution, or only to the normal distribution?

Comment: Does *what* apply to any kind of distribution?  What does "this" refer to, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The expression $Q(-x)=\Phi(x)$ only holds when $\Phi$ (and thus also $Q$) is symmetric around $0$, like for the Gaussian distribution.

One example where this is not the case is the uniform distribution:

[image]

PS. Just to be clear: The $Q$ function you refer to in your [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) is *not* the same as the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).